# How to Add only 5 dynamic textbox and how to show current week only in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one requirement generate dynamic textbox and datepicker in javascript using jsp dynamic textbox generated correctly but now i want restrict user to add upto 5 dynamic textbox also in datepicker i want to show only current week not whole month i'm coded for both but nothing is working don't know why adding screenshot for more understand and also attaching expecting datepicker

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
         <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

        <script>

          //script for allow only 5 


        $(function () {
    $("#date_ex").datepicker({
        firstDay: 0,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            //var sunday = new Date("June 2, 2013 00:00:00");
            var sunday = new Date();
            sunday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            //alert(sunday.getDay() + ' : ' + sunday.getDate() + ' : ' + (sunday.getDay() || 0) + ' : ' + sunday.getTime());
            sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - (sunday.getDay() || 0));
            var saturday = new Date(sunday.getTime());
            saturday.setDate(sunday.getDate() + 5);
            return [(date >= sunday && date <= saturday), ''];
        }
    });
    $("#date_ex").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
});



            <script> 


            var index = 0; 
            var name='<%=test%>';



            function getinput() 
            { 
            index ++; 
            var singleRecord = ""; 

            singleRecord += "Project_name : <input type='text' name='txt_project_name"+index+"'>";
            singleRecord += "Project/Task : <input type='text' name='txt_Header"+index+"'>"; 
            singleRecord += "Department : <input type='text' name='txt_Department"+index+"'>"; 
            singleRecord += "Description : <input type='text' name='txt_description"+index+"'>"; 
            singleRecord += "Date : <input type='text' id='date_ex" + index+ "' name='txt_date"+index+"'><br/>"; 
            singleRecord += "<hr/>"; 
            $("#inputs").append(singleRecord); 
            $( "#date_ex" +index).datepicker(); 
            $("#count").val(index); 

    //this is for generate only 5 textbox
            if(index.length<6)
            {
                alert('error');
            }

            }


            </script> 
            </head> 

            <body background="images\blue_background.jpg">
            <form action="EmployeeVendorValidation.jsp" method="post" autocomplete="off"> 


                 <br><br><br><br>    
            <input type="hidden" name="count" id="count"/> 
            <input type="hidden" name="date_ex" id="date_ex"/> 



            <div id="inputs"> 
            </div> 
            <button type="button" onclick="getinput()" class="button button5">Add</button> 
            <button type="button" onclick="removeElement()" class="button button5">Remove</button> 

            &nbsp; 
            <button type="submit" class="button button2">Submit</button> 


            </form> 
            </body>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent add more then 5

```
 function getinput() 
            { 

            if($('[name*="txt_project_name"]').length >= 5) return false;

            //your code here

            }
```

Show Current Week Only

```
        var week = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6'];
        var date = new Date(), curDay = date.getDay();
        var minDate = curDay;
        var maxDate =week.length -  week.indexOf(String(curDay))-1;
        console.log(minDate,maxDate)
        $( "#date_ex" +index).datepicker({
        maxDate: "+"+maxDate+"d",
        minDate:  "-"+minDate+"d"
        });
```

Full fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/9LmL0787/

Comment: thank you @pandian_snkl its working as expect thank you very very much :)